# Embed Rally Iteration Status into Webpage

Tags: rally

Where I work, we have a common tool that we use to pull information from various sources regarding the health of our project.  Normally this is done by putting the url for the information/chart into an html document and then embedding that document as an iFrame into our company's tool.

In this case, I want to be able to embed the Iteration Status (swim lanes) in Rally into this app.  This chart need only be read only.  I've managed to figure out the Rally API for several other reports, but I can't seem to find a way to pull the iteration status out.  Has anyone done this or know how to do it?  I would be forever grateful for any guidance on this!

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able do this.  The following guides should be helpful for embedding your app:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/embedding_apps

And you can find the newest available source for the Iteration Tracking page by downloading this app catalog zip:

https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/releases/download/2.1.1/2.1.1.zip

The source will be in html/iterationtrackingboard/App-uncompressed.html

Comment: I tried this, but this only shows the Stories, Defect etc. and not the Stats Banner, 
Any idea on how to get that Banner shown?

I am trying to build an app which shows the Banner along with some other Summarized info.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately that stats banner used to be included in the app, but is now not.  Closest thing is probably all the stats banner code in the Release Tracking Board: https://github.com/RallyCommunity/PSITrackingApp
Maybe you can port that over?